# mysql combining data from multiple records in single record

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a school database system based on php mysql. the basic structure is as below:

```
Table Class-Details of all classes.
```

[image]

```
Table Student-Details of all students
```

[image]

```
Table Semester-Details of all Semesters
```

[image]

```
Table class–Semester. This table solves many to many relation, primary key- IDs of both class and semester.
```

[image]

```
Table Subject -Details of all Subjects
```

[image]

```
Table class–Subject. This table solves many to many relation, primary key- IDs of both class and semester.
```

[image]

```
Table marks- consists of student ID, Subject ID, Semester ID, Marks Achieved.Foreign Key ClassID, SemesterID, SubjectID
```

[image]

I am trying to get a table in below mentioned format:
[image]

```
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 53
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

So far I could achieve individual marks of subjects in every record 
my query:

```
SELECT 
                m.MarkID, m.studentID, 
                sm.ExamName, sb.Subject, 
                sm.MaxMarks, m.MarksRecvd  

                FROM marks AS m

                RIGHT JOIN student AS st 
                ON m.studentID=st.studentID

                RIGHT JOIN semester AS sm
                ON m.ExamID=sm.ExamID

                RIGHT JOIN subject AS sb 
                ON m.SubjectID=sb.SubjectID

                WHERE m.studentID = $studentID
```

Please help me on this... I am getting a record for every mark recvd like below.

[image]

However I want to group all semester marks in one row like below:
[image]

Friends pls let me know if my query is clear

Comment: How do you get your values for each semester?  Sample data would help make this clearer.

Comment: you should show your effort.

Comment: I am having a table called class with many to many relationship with semesters table. So far I have created-
SELECT 
    m.MarkID, m.studentID, 
    sm.ExamName, sb.Subject, 
    sm.MaxMarks, m.MarksRecvd  
    
    FROM marks AS m
    
    RIGHT JOIN student AS st 
    ON m.studentID=st.studentID
    
    RIGHT JOIN semester AS sm
    ON m.ExamID=sm.ExamID
    
    RIGHT JOIN subject AS sb 
    ON m.SubjectID=sb.SubjectID
    
    WHERE m.studentID = $studentID

Comment: yes amit, I have updated my query above which shows data from multiple records

Comment: Hello folks. Please help me on this...

Comment: The problem is that the relation you've given us is strange and complex, and without actual data it's next to impossible to figure out where any errors could be coming from. Perhaps fill the table with some fake data and export it to SQL so we could try to work.

Comment: @jhecht: I hope this is a little clear

Comment: Hi, have you thought about using a stored procedure to collect your information and write it into a temporary table and at the end just call a SELECT * FROM tmpTable?